# Animation flickering

Tags: css, html, sass

I have a rectangular div object which is moving slowly up and down (infinite animation). That div object has a 1px width orange border (for example). Is there any way to prevent border flickering?

I assume this is because of vertical moving (left and right border are not  flickering) and has something to do with how image is rendering on monitor, but is there something I could do to prevent it? I also need that border to be visible all the time.

```css
@keyframes float {
        
        0% {
            transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    
        50% {
            transform: translateY(-15px);
        }
    
        100% {
            transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    }

body {
  background-color:#000;
  padding-top:200px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background-color:#000;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  margin:0 auto;
  animation: float 5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Setting to 2px already makes it look better

Comment: I know :) but it shouldn't be 2px :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - it doesn´t flick but you need a even valued border for it to work (2px here).

Added a no-flick class to the element.

```css
@keyframes float {
        
        0% {
            transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    
        50% {
            transform: translateY(-15px);
        }
    
        100% {
            transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    }
    

body {
  background-color:#000;
  padding-top:200px;
}

div {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  background-color:#000;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  margin:0 auto;
  animation: float 5s infinite;
  
}
.no-flick{-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
```

```html
<div class="no-flick"></div>
```

Comment: @Nick whats special with value 1. any documentation or bug ?

Comment: I just read the same info here: 
https://coderwall.com/p/gmpjzg/prevent-flickering-on-css3-transitions-transforms-in-webkit
Check the comment from avigogetit

Comment: It has to be 1px. I've also tried with background-color on the element and margin in subelement. but it's the same.

Comment: I´ve also tried replacing your border with a border-shadow of 1px with no luck - still flicks.